# spring boot 3 profile property values getting overridden in boostrap.yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

Recently trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 3, but facing property issue.
My bootstrap yml looks like below,
When I run with profile dev, the configserver url is always getting connected to qa, basically whichever is declared last.

This is working fine in 2.7.X version of spring, but not in spring boot 3

```
spring:
  application:
    name: appname
  profiles:
    active: ${spring.profiles.active}
    include:
      - global-defaults
    group:
      dev:
        - config-server-dev
        - cloud-config-dev
      qa:
        - config-server-qa
        - cloud-config-qa

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: config-server-dev
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://urltoconfigserverdev
      label: master

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: config-server-qa
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      uri: http://urltoconfigserverqa
      label: master

---
```

But the same is working fine if add the property migration pom dependency. which is not suggested for higher environments.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which Spring Cloud version are you using?

Comment: <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>

Answer (score 0):

If adding the properties migrator fixes the problem, it's likely that your configuration file is using a configuration property name that's been removed after deprecation. I'm not seeing [anything specific to Spring Boot in the changelog](https://%20https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Configuration-Changelog), maybe this is due to a change in spring cloud config? The properties migrator should print WARN logs during startup, looking at those should tell you what needs fixing.

Comment: I don't see any WARN in the startup logs either.